# Android Studio Location API stopped Working No Build Error

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, android-studio

Well for some reason when I run the application it shows no errors but when I run the emulation and open the app in emulation it keep saying "unfortunality mylocationfind has stopped"

Dont know what the error is but here is the code if anyone can help.

I am running it on 4.0.3 but the emulation is a nexus 5 21 Google API. Could it be that? For somereason the 4.0.3 15 wont work on mine as it shows only a black screen on the emulation as I dont use x86.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {
    //private LocationManager locationManager;
    private Location currentLocation;
    private TextView locationText;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    buildGoogleApiClient();
}

private void updateDisplay(){
    if (currentLocation==null){
        locationText.setText("determining your location...");
    } else {
        locationText.setText(
                String.format("Your location:\n%2f, %.2f", currentLocation.getLatitude(),
                        currentLocation.getLongitude()));

    }
}

private LocationListener mListener = new LocationListener(){
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
        currentLocation=location;
        updateDisplay();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
    }
};

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    //currentLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    updateDisplay();
    //locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mListener);
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    //locationManager.removeUpdates(mListener);
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient(){
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

}
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
currentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
        mGoogleApiClient);
    updateDisplay();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

}

Comment: Are you running the standard emulator or Genymotion? I believe there are problems running Google maps on the standard emulator due to things like lack of Google Play Services. Testing on physical devices would be best, if possible.